# Defining a Hazelcast MapStore for Key-Ranges

Tags: hazelcast

When we want to implement the MapStore interface we only have the method `loadAll` for initializing the map. Therefore you have to provide a set of keys to load into the map. How do you handle the situation when you have date / time as primary key. Intuitively one would define a key range `where tst between a and b`. But since we only can provide a Set we have to pre-fetch all the possible date-time values (via SQL or whatever). And the next time the IMap will start to hammer the database fetching every key one by one. Is this the best approach? Isn't there a more convenient way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be to stop thinking about the maps as if they were tables in a relational database. Try to think in terms that conform to the semantics of a Map (if you are using a Map as there are other distributed collections in Hazelcast). For example, you have to keep in mind that you can only make queries about objects that are available in memory as the semantics of query applies only to the case in which Hazelcast is used as a data grid and not as a cache. If semantics is the use of a cache, you should limit your access by key, as you would proceed with a traditional map in Java.

For example, when it comes to a data grid, you must think that access to the database will occur typically only to respond to disaster recovery scenarios. Therefore, the initial data loading from disk to memory may strongly hit the database, but that would only occur in cases of recovery, so that it is not such a major handicap. In the case of use of caching, yes it would be important to be very efficient when planning your persistence strategy since access to the database will be more frequent.

If you provide further information about what it's your particular use case, especially regarding eviction policies, maybe I might help you more.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah would agree with that, otherwise you're mentioned option (using a SQL to find the keys) sounds like the way to go.

Comment: Sorry, no, this is not helpful. It is not about how we threat a map it is how we fill a map initially with range data - without hammering a productive database on startup that much. Maybe one could point out the starting point class where I could fork my own implementation of hc for initially fetiching data

Comment: Sorry but I disagree. IMHO it's very important to know what it's your use case in order to establish a persistence strategy. And I insist that what matters first is whether you are treating Hazelcast as a cache solution or a data grid. I've edited my previous answer to better explain my point of view.

Comment: I really think of it as a key/value store for this case. but with the special case that this keys are time series and therefore ordered and can have gaps. I am thinking of developing an navigable map implementation as you can find on the github issue site